# Sending Query to non-Queryable action method

Tags: breeze

I have a query:

```
var query = entityQuery.from('Reports').where(predicate);
manager.executeQuery(query).then(function(data){ var reportFile = data.results[0];});
```

To describe - I create predicate, send query to server which returns path to a generated report file made of entities selected by predicate. Serverside looks something like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public string Reports(){
    var result = _contextProvider.Context.Items.Include('Subitem1').Include('Subitem2').Include('Subitem1.SubSubitem1').ToList();
    var ex = new ExportController();
    return ex.ExportResults(result);
}
```

What I would expect this to do is to get into variable 'result' only items selected by previously parsed 'predicate', but instead, I get all items, predicate is ignored. I've tried to add [Queryable] in front of the action method, but then I get error that action method cannot return string. Method returns path to generated report.

Is it possible to do this with Breeze?

The current idea to avoid the problem is to have this action method return IQueryable containing all selected items, then have client send all those items back to server and then call the ExportController. Considering my app should have a bit more than few kB data, it doesn't seem like long term solution.

Comment: Are you using server-side Breeze controller attribute?  If not, and also if you are not using an IQueryable, then the server will simply ignore your predicate.  Another option is to create parameters and use withParameters() on your query and receive them on the server side for processing.

Comment: The whole code is in the question. Return value is string because I'm sending back a download link - so it's not an IQueryable. It's possible to send to server using withParameters() but considering my filtering is in whole parsed on client-side, I hoped that I wouldn't need to make parser on server as well.